# Encoding issue with request package on Amazon

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, request-promise

I use [request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), but got no luck on Amazon.

The result body is unreadable. The following line is an example of its last line

�e���k�i�(h����k�Db���5�4�B�ՅU`��aU�n��n�U\�Pi��^�b���Va��RX���k�j�\�jT���]�^���R^n�T��lf�Y���Y��cQ\�i�b��[Z��c�c���QR��뙓���#A�����̭[�

And this is the source code, which is modified from the sample at *request* package' documentation. The header option is copied from inspecting request made on browser.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://amazon.com',
  headers: {
    Host: 'www.amazon.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',
    Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': 'session-id=133-2909347-2331161; session-id-time=2082787201l; ubid-main=133-6665239-1349866; x-wl-uid=1aNDIdKODvHoUb76/A5QCVkYIeF+LZ2pqpMM8JQo5cZtjNDdHgNRoWECTkFGXZoTqtKVj+c9qEP8=; session-token=MHjBQ6hhjmeBpdoMKWKQ6WMXNB9eEbOfg8cmduApylILgTnueB2PGZ8MTQorIK/eSqPuf7KBubSqfXoPqvOvH/bJeE/paux5LMshzbb8fmXnGzbkXUh12BjkZG35xlP4KKX+6VLPkrFZuU3Slfh5Nsjur8SjZMzOij932V+cM11zWnwqnKagocDkT/POoUm7; aws-priv=eyJ2IjoxLCJldSI6MCwic3QiOjB9; aws-target-static-id=1542006876176-207181; aws-target-visitor-id=1542006876178-631907.22_43; aws-target-data=%7B%22support%22%3A%221%22%7D; s_fid=6A3F9D736EAAEA1E-083ED2A6AC4959CD; s_dslv=1548597813996; s_vn=1573542876770%26vn%3D15; regStatus=registered; aws-ubid-main=344-3173447-5188468; csm-hit=tb:77V9SZC624TV2TXAN0TH+s-77V9SZC624TV2TXAN0TH|1557067076013&adb:adblk_yes&t:1557067076013; lc-main=en_US; aws-session-id=139-2216932-3496407; aws-session-id-time=1548043513l; __utma=194891197.192669939.1547951660.1547951660.1547951660.1; __utmz=194891197.1547951660.1.1.utmccn=(referral)|utmcsr=signin.aws.amazon.com|utmcct=/signin|utmcmd=referral; aws-session-token="Hn6keYPBLheD1tDkUYibx3GbbMfdgW/kagGmWu41Jk6zxEZZvHxbP+2QSxWb7qigqtXzH/WXRgPCnhuiVFj0BX18B20JcRFa6i/AINKs2aPxHFTLow6oYblEBeSfVYu73ZVdOYcEo4/6MnY2Mg81sC4qwgFmjZvo8AjcRI17jYzSTiGDjBYJ9xFLmaB+ncbqfUSnJC/o114IkZo9tOFWuKoxU7YmjzyxvFZLZTFKbqQ="; sess-aws-at-main="yKdGmYUEP+ikBbaVbs5dokfkQL2L+0TpBaj3U20sSQU="; aws-userInfo=%7B%22arn%22%3A%22arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A453322389300%3Aroot%22%2C%22alias%22%3A%22%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22zenji%22%2C%22keybase%22%3A%22%22%2C%22issuer%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fsignin.aws.amazon.com%2Fsignin%22%7D; aws-business-metrics-last-visit=1547952685948; i18n-prefs=USD; sp-cdn="L5Z9:VN"; skin=noskin',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',`?

Comment: Hi, @ChrisWhite, it works! The r esult's format is as expected. Could you explain in more details?
Another thing is that if I remove the header option, then the result is again unreadable.

Comment: OK. By using that `Accept-Encoding` header with `gzip, deflate`, you're telling Amazon that it should compress the response back to you, which it did, but you're not decompressing it before you log it.